# How to mix razor and javascript in single line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

This works

```
@Html.Action("LiveBlogHeader", "Blog", new { liveMatchItemId = "12" })
```

I want to set hidden field's value in it. Something like this

```
@Html.Action("LiveBlogHeader", "Blog", new { liveMatchItemId =  @:document.getElementById('liveMatchItemId').value })
```

which apparently not working. Can you please help?

Comment: `@Html.Action()` is processed on the server; how would it be able to find anything in the client-side `document`? You'll need to use a separate JavaScript function to set it.

Comment: First of all, this `liveMatchItemId` in your html element is populated with your `Model` or `ViewBag´? So you could just use the same here, instead of trying to mix javascript. If this tag with this `liveMatchItemId` resides in a layout page and you don't use your `Model` for it, then it has a fixed value, or you set its value with javascript, then you must follow what @MikeMcCaughan suggested, and use javascript instead of razor.

Comment: `Html.Action()` is a method that renders a partial view during the rendering of the main page that calls it. It all happens before the html to send to the browser. A javascript variable does not even exist at that point, and using a _JavaScript function to set it_ as noted above cannot work and would make no sense. If you want to update the DOM based on some value in the client (e.g. the value of a textbox that is changed by the user), then use ajax to call a server method based on the value and return a partial view.